# How do I send keys to phone field using webdriver in firefox?

Tags: java, testing, xpath, webdriver, testng

```
   package erjan.testNG.personal_cabinet;

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

    public class Login_test {
      WebDriver firefox ;
      @Test
      public void f() {
          WebElement login_form

 = firefox.findElement(By.id("login-form")) ;

      WebElement phone_field = firefox.findElement(By.className("phone-username")) ;

      WebElement password_field = firefox.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"text\"]"));

      Assert.assertNotNull(login_form) ;
      Assert.assertNotNull(phone_field) ;
      Assert.assertNotNull(password_field);


      phone_field.sendKeys("4457653245");

      String x = phone_field.getText() ;
      System.out.println("here we go!!!!!!!!! " + x) ;


  }

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {

      firefox = new FirefoxDriver();
      firefox.get("http://test.naimi.me/astana/login");

  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {
  }

}
```

[image: rrr]

I see firefox open but i don't see my number getting inserted in the phone field!
or maybe it happens fast? or maybe because it has to be standardized in some way?

should I somehow "slow down" the input to see it typed in number-by-number?
should I use explicit wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you aren't seeing it, but are you getting the value in x?  Rather than slowing down the code, try to run it through Debug mode in your IDE or include some logging statements to help you see what your code is doing.

One thing to try, if there is pre-existing text in the field, is clearing that text field first:

```
phone_field.clear();
phone_field.sendKeys("4457653245");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a matter of timing.

Many forms may request an activation before text is accepted so 
an approach worth is find the element, click on it and then insert the text.

```
phone_field.click();
phone_field.sendKeys("4457653245");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
getDriver().findElement(locator).sendKeys(Keys.chord("phone number formatted"));
```